# How to pass value to controller?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

When I try to pass the `url` value to the controller `action`, `action` is not getting the required value.

I'm sending the value like this:

```
function value(url,id)
{
    alert(url);
    document.getElementById('rating').innerHTML=id;
    var params = 'artist='+id;
    alert(params);
    // var newurl='http://localhost/songs_full/public/eslresult/ratesong/userid/1/id/27';
    var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(newurl,{method: 'post',parameters:params,onComplete: loadResponse});        
    //var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(url,{method:'POST',parameters:params,onComplete: load});
    //alert(myAjax);

}

function load(http) 
{
    alert('success');
}
```

and in the controller I have:

```
public function ratesongAction()
{
    $user=$_POST['rating'];
    echo $user;
    $post= $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    //echo $post;
    $ratesongid= $this->_getParam('id');
}
```

But still not getting the result.
I am using zend framework.

Comment: Am I the only one who spent a minute trying to figure out what a "topass value" was?  (as opposed to a bottomass value?)

Comment: @Pretzel LOL - fixed the "topass" to "to pass"

Comment: It looks like this using Zend Framework for the backend, this should be tagged as appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need alot more information here... How are you calling these functions? Are the values being passed at any stage in the chain? You mention "*action*", what are you actually referring to?

Further on that - if you mean that the values are not being handled within the PHP section, are you using the correctly named parameters? I see your Javascript code mentioned one parameter called "**artist**", but the PHP code mentions "**rating**" alone.

Comment: my action code is

public function ratesongAction()
        {
                   print_r($_POST['artist']);
                   echo $user;
    $post= $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    //echo $post;
   $ratesongid= $this->_getParam('id');
   //$ratesong= $post['artist'];
      // echo "ratesong".$ratesong;
       $lyrics = new Model_DbTable_Lyrics();
       $result = $lyrics->getLyricsNameOnId($ratesongid);
      
       /*json object*/
       $jason_result = Zend_Json::encode($result);
       $this->view->SongDetail = $jason_result;
       $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('layout');

Comment: my view is
<a href="#" class="undone" rel="1" id="1" onmouseover="javascript:display(1);" onmouseout="javascript:hide1(1);" onClick="value('<?php echo $this->url(array('controller'=>'eslresult','action'=>'ratesong','artist'=>'1'))?>  ','1');">star one</a>

Comment: and js is
function value(url,id)
    {
   alert(url);
     document.getElementById('rating').innerHTML=id;
     var params = 'artist='+id;
  alert(params);
  var newurl='http://localhost/songs_full/public/eslresult/ratesong/userid/';
   var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(newurl,{method: 'post',parameters:params[0],onComplete: load});        
   //var myAjax = new Ajax.Request(url,{method:'POST',parameters:params,onComplete: load});
   //alert(myAjax);

    }
 function load(http) 
    {
 
       alert('success');
 
    }